# Showing parsed XML data in Fragments with parsing only on app start and on location change

Tags: android

Greetings,

I'm new to android and I'm trying to make my own weather app.
It's working as it should but if I switch between tabs the data gets parsed all again which results in freeze of the app while data is loading.

I want my app to parse the data on first start then save the data and parse it again if location has changed or X time has passed (lets say 20min)

**EDIT:** Just so it is clear, I just need a little guidance into the right direction on how to achieve this. Should I store the data in local xml instead of direct parsing?
Or is there any other way of storing the parsed data?

This is my code so far:

One of the tabs showing data

```
    public class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "Tab2Fragment";

    ArrayList<Dan> dnevi2;
    GPSTracker gps;
    Postaje postaje;
    String[] najblizjaPostaja;
    boolean update = true;

    TextView[] vNaprej;
    TextView[] vNaprej2;
    ImageView[] ikone;
    int count = 0;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vreme_napoved,container,false);

        postaje = new Postaje();
        najblizjaPostaja = postaje.getPostajeNapoved(getContext());

        //..
views
..//
        napoved();
        ShowIt();
        setRetainInstance(true);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setRetainInstance(true);
        ShowIt();
        if(update) {
            napoved();
            update = false;
        }
    }

    private void ShowIt(){

        for (Dan dan : dnevi2) {

            String text = dan.getDatum() + "\n" + dan.getRazmere();
            String text2 = dan.getMinTemp() + getString(R.string.celzija) + " / " + dan.getMaxTemp() + getString(R.string.celzija);
            vNaprej[count].setText(text);
            vNaprej2[count].setText(text2);
            ikone[count].setImageResource(dan.getIcon());
            count++;
        }count=0;

    }
    private void napoved() {
        //          4 DNEVNA NAPOVED-->

        XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
        try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            final XmlPullParser parserVnaprej = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();
            final URL urlVnaprej = new URL(najblizjaPostaja[0]);
            parserVnaprej.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);

            Thread threadVnaprej = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {

                        final InputStream insVnaprej = urlVnaprej.openStream();
                        parserVnaprej.setInput(insVnaprej, null);
                        dnevi2 = parseVnaprej(parserVnaprej);
                        insVnaprej.close();
                    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            threadVnaprej.start();
            threadVnaprej.join();

//catches
        //          


    public ArrayList<Dan> parseVnaprej(XmlPullParser parserVnaprej) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException
    {
        ArrayList<Dan> Dan = null;
        int eventType = parserVnaprej.getEventType();
        Dan dnevi2 = null;

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String name;
            switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                    Dan = new ArrayList();
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    name = parserVnaprej.getName();
                    if (name.equals("metData")) {
                        dnevi2 = new Dan();
                    } else if (dnevi2 != null) {
                        if (name.equals("valid_day")) {
                            dnevi2.setDatum(CETStran(parserVnaprej.nextText()));
                        } else if (name.equals("tn")) {
                            dnevi2.setMinTemp(parserVnaprej.nextText());
                        }else if (name.equals("tx")) {
                            dnevi2.setMaxTemp(parserVnaprej.nextText());
                        }else if (name.equals("nn_shortText")) {
                            String text=parserVnaprej.nextText();
                            dnevi2.setRazmere(text);
                            dnevi2.setIcon(Ikona(text));
                        }else if (name.equals("dd_longText")) {
                            dnevi2.setVeter(parserVnaprej.nextText());
                        }

                    }

                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    name = parserVnaprej.getName();
                    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("metData") && dnevi2 != null){
                        if (Dan != null) {
                            Dan.add(dnevi2);
                        }
                    }
            }
            eventType = parserVnaprej.next();
        }
        return Dan;
    }
```

Postaje (weather stations)

```
public class Postaje {


    GPSTracker gps;
    Context mContext;
    double lat;
    double lon;
    String postaja;
    String[] najblizjaPostaja;
    String[] najblizjaPostajaNapoved;
    String base = ("http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/");
    int count;
    private boolean asked = false;
    double latMin = 0;
    double lonMin = 0;
    double latMax = 0;
    double lonMax = 0;
    float[] izid = new float[1];
    double testing = 10000000;


    public String getPostaja() {
        return postaja;
    }

    public void setPostaja(String postaja) {
        this.postaja = postaja;
    }

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(double lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }


    String[] urlPostajeTrenutno = new String[]{
            urls
    };

    String[] urlPostajeZjutrajPopoldne = new String[]{
            urls
    };

    String[] urlPostajeTriDni = new String[]{
            urls
    };

    String[] urlModelskaNapoved = new String[]{
           urls
    };


    XmlPullParserFactory postajePullParserFactory;

    public String[] getPostajeTrenutno(Context context) {

        gps = new GPSTracker(context);

        najblizjaPostaja = new String[5];
        try {
            postajePullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            final XmlPullParser parserPostajeTrenutno = postajePullParserFactory.newPullParser();

            parserPostajeTrenutno.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            Thread threadVremeTrenutno = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        for (count = 0; count < urlPostajeTrenutno.length; count++) {
                            final URL postajeTrenutnoURL = new URL(base + urlPostajeTrenutno[count]);
                            final InputStream trenutno = postajeTrenutnoURL.openStream();
                            parserPostajeTrenutno.setInput(trenutno, null);
                            ArrayList<Postaje> postajeTrenutnoList = parsePostajaTrenutno(parserPostajeTrenutno);


                            for (Postaje postaje : postajeTrenutnoList) {
                                Location.distanceBetween(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), postaje.getLat(), postaje.getLon(), izid);
                                if (testing > izid[0]) {
                                    testing = izid[0];
                                    najblizjaPostaja[0] = base + urlPostajeTrenutno[count];

                                }
                            }
                            trenutno.close();
                        }
                        testing = 10000000;

                        for (count = 0; count < urlPostajeZjutrajPopoldne.length; count++) {
                            final URL postajeZjutrajPopoldneURL = new URL(base + urlPostajeZjutrajPopoldne[count]);
                            final InputStream trenutno = postajeZjutrajPopoldneURL.openStream();
                            parserPostajeTrenutno.setInput(trenutno, null);
                            ArrayList<Postaje> postajeTrenutnoList = parsePostajaTrenutno(parserPostajeTrenutno);


                            for (Postaje postaje : postajeTrenutnoList) {
                                Location.distanceBetween(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), postaje.getLat(), postaje.getLon(), izid);
                                if (testing > izid[0]) {
                                    testing = izid[0];
                                    najblizjaPostaja[1] = base + urlPostajeZjutrajPopoldne[count];
                                    Log.e("Postaje...",najblizjaPostaja[1]);
                                }
                            }
                            trenutno.close();
                        }
                        testing = 10000000;

                    //cathes
                }
            });
            threadVremeTrenutno.start();
            threadVremeTrenutno.join();

        //catches
        return najblizjaPostaja;
    }



    public String[] getPostajeNapoved(Context context) {

        gps = new GPSTracker(context);
        if(!asked) {
            gps.canGetLocation();
            asked = true;
        }
        najblizjaPostajaNapoved = new String[5];
        try {
            postajePullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            final XmlPullParser parserPostajeTrenutno = postajePullParserFactory.newPullParser();

            parserPostajeTrenutno.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            Thread threadVremeNapoved = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        for (count = 0; count < urlPostajeTriDni.length; count++) {
                            final URL postajeTrenutnoURL = new URL(base + urlPostajeTriDni[count]);
                            final InputStream trenutno = postajeTrenutnoURL.openStream();
                            parserPostajeTrenutno.setInput(trenutno, null);
                            ArrayList<Postaje> postajeTrenutnoList = parsePostajaTrenutno(parserPostajeTrenutno);


                            for (Postaje postaje : postajeTrenutnoList) {
                                Location.distanceBetween(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), postaje.getLat(), postaje.getLon(), izid);
                                if (testing > izid[0]) {
                                    testing = izid[0];

                                    najblizjaPostajaNapoved[0] = base + urlPostajeTriDni[count];
                                }
                            }
                            trenutno.close();
                        }
                        testing = 10000000;

                        for (count = 0; count < urlModelskaNapoved.length; count++) {
                            final URL postajeTrenutnoURL = new URL(base + urlModelskaNapoved[count]);
                            final InputStream trenutno = postajeTrenutnoURL.openStream();
                            parserPostajeTrenutno.setInput(trenutno, null);
                            ArrayList<Postaje> postajeTrenutnoList = parsePostajaTrenutno(parserPostajeTrenutno);


                            for (Postaje postaje : postajeTrenutnoList) {
                                Location.distanceBetween(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude(), postaje.getLat(), postaje.getLon(), izid);
                                if (testing > izid[0]) {
                                    testing = izid[0];

                                    najblizjaPostajaNapoved[1] = base + urlModelskaNapoved[count];
                                }
                            }
                            trenutno.close();
                        }
                        testing = 10000000;

                    //caches
                }
            });
            threadVremeNapoved.start();
            threadVremeNapoved.join();

        //caches
        return najblizjaPostajaNapoved;
    }

            private ArrayList<Postaje> parsePostajaTrenutno (XmlPullParser parserPostajeTrenutno) throws
            XmlPullParserException, IOException {

                ArrayList<Postaje> Postaje = null;
                int eventType = parserPostajeTrenutno.getEventType();
                Postaje postajeTrenutnoList = null;
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    String name;
                    switch (eventType) {
                        case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                            Postaje = new ArrayList();
                            break;
                        case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                            name = parserPostajeTrenutno.getName();
                            if (name.equals("metData")) {
                                postajeTrenutnoList = new Postaje();
                            } else if (postajeTrenutnoList != null) {
                                if (name.equals("domain_lat")) {
                                    postajeTrenutnoList.setLat(Double.valueOf(parserPostajeTrenutno.nextText()));
                                } else if (name.equals("domain_lon")) {
                                    postajeTrenutnoList.setLon(Double.valueOf(parserPostajeTrenutno.nextText()));
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                            break;
                        case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                            name = parserPostajeTrenutno.getName();
                            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("metData") && postajeTrenutnoList != null) {
                                Postaje.add(postajeTrenutnoList);
                            }
                    }
                    eventType = parserPostajeTrenutno.next();
                }
                return Postaje;
    }
}
```

My GPS

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    boolean asked = false;
    public  Boolean update = true;

    private final Context mContext;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 100000; // 10 meters
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 20; // 1 minute
    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private static final String TAG_RUNTIME_PERMISSION = "TAG_RUNTIME_PERMISSION";

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        if (getUpdate()) {
            getLocation();
        }
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                 showSettingsAlert();
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        requestRuntimePermission(getApplication(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();

                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                setUpdate(false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
    }
    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }
    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean getUpdate(){
        return update;
    }

    public void setUpdate(boolean update){
        this.update = update;
    }
    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        if(!asked) {
            requestRuntimePermission(getApplication(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            asked=true;
        }
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }
    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                positiveButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFE1FCEA"));
                positiveButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000"));
            }
        });
        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();

            }
        });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private boolean hasRuntimePermission(Context context, String runtimePermission) {
        boolean ret = false;

        // Get current android os version.
        int currentAndroidVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

        // Build.VERSION_CODES.M's value is 23.
        if (currentAndroidVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // Only android version 23+ need to check runtime permission.
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, runtimePermission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ret = true;
            }
        } else {
            ret = true;
        }
        return ret;
    }
//
//    /* Request app user to allow the needed runtime permission.
//       It will popup a confirm dialog , user can click allow or deny. */
    private void requestRuntimePermission(Application activity, String runtimePermission, int requestCode) {
        Log.e(TAG, "requesting" );
        requestPermissions((Activity)mContext, new String[]{runtimePermission}, requestCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        setUpdate(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need Indeterminate ProgressBar to rotate until data loads every time. While loading data, just disable background clicks to avoid conflicts.

Comment: But I want to avoid loading data every time user swipes between tabs..
Ideally not needing internet after parsing data. Since how it is now if I disable internet after switching tabs they are just blank..

Comment: Then i recommend you to use Sqlite with openHelper.